# Create a tetrahedral mesh from a closed triangular mesh

Tags: volume, mesh

I'm looking for an algorithm (or implementation) to create a tetrahedral mesh from a closed (i.e. without holes) 3D triangular mesh.

The best solution would be an open source application that can import mesh files (e.g. OBJ, STL and VTK), display them, and provide an option to tetrahedralize the mesh. But I'm also fine with command line tools, or just outlines of an algorithm.

Some background — I'm using Blender on a Linux system to design the surface meshes. Eventually I plan to implement a tetrahedralization algorithm in either Python or MATLAB.

I already stumbled upon a few application names while searching for a good mesher, but so far I don't have any concrete results. Any information on relevant papers, algorithms or implementations is therefore most welcome!

Applications found mentioned so far:

- MeshLab
- TetGen
- Gmsh
- Rhino

A few relevant terms:

- Delaunay (3D)
- Advancing Front Meshing

Comment: Octree might work for you.  Google it and see: http://catiadoc.free.fr/online/cfyuganalysis_C2/cfyuganalysis3dmeshpart.htm

Comment: Your question is probably a better fit for [SE Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Jaime Thanks, can I somehow move this question to SciComp.SE myself?

Comment: You can flag it and ask a moderator to move it for you.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the GEOGRAM software that I'm developping:

http://alice.loria.fr/software/geogram/doc/html/index.html
(it supports STL and OBJ file format).

Under the scene, it uses tetgen. It also has visualization with OpenGL.